# c# global keyboard hooks with source id

Tags: keyboard, hook, global

I want to make global hook keyboard.
I have tried this code [msdn blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/) it is work, but...
I need to identify used keyboard when i catch the key.
There is have two keyboard and it should works only for one.

Comment: You cannot identify the (hardware) source of a keyboard event in a low-level keyboard hook. You'll have to go with a different approach, like [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/raw-input).

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I need. I try make it like in HIDmacros